# Sonar default authentication failing

Tags: sonarqube

I have a Sonar install running on a windows server using MySql 5.1

I left my admin password at its default of **admin** and created a second users password all of which worked. After a break of a few months of not really using Sonar I tried to log in and it constantly fails to authenticate on both accounts.

These are the steps I have taken to resolve it:

1. Update to the latest Sonar 2.8 which successfully updated the database
2. Set the password with sql I got from the Sonar docs.

   update users set crypted_password = '88c991e39bb88b94178123a849606905ebf440f5', salt='6522f3c5007ae910ad690bb1bdbf264a34884c6d' where login = 'admin'
3. Stopped the MySQLserver to make sure its connecting to the database I'm expecting it too. (It was)
4. Set the log level to DEBUG to see if there is anything in the logs but there was nothing.

I know I could drop the database and start from scratch but ideally I would like to keep the 12 months of build history I have.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The reason the reset of the accounts didn't work was that there were two sql server instances running and I was re-setting the admin account above on the wrong instance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you reset the accounts as per the [Sonar FAQ](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Frequently+Asked+Questions)?

Comment: new link: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Authentication#Authentication-FAQ

Comment: Also this new link is rotten away, here is a general authentication doc: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARqube71/Authentication

Comment: none of the above links are working :-(